# Когда и какие объекты лучше хранить в сессии?

Tags: веб-программирование, сессия

Объекты можно передавать через request и через session. (касательно javaEE). Интересует, когда и какие объекты лучше хранить в сессии?

Comment: скажем так, доверять данным из request нельзя, а данным из сессии, в общем случае, можно.

Как правило в сессию кладут данные юзера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то мне думается, что в сессии хранить данные - очень безопасно.
Ну а хранить в сессии можно какие угодно объекты. Но в основном хранят данные пользователя (логин и роль, или что-то там такое, что вам надо).

Ну и еще. Бывают такие ситуации, что некоторые объекты очень удобно хранить в сессии (например, действие из нескольких шагов), вот их тоже в сессии храните.

Comment: а что насчет размера сессии? Нагрузка на сервер?

Comment: Ну, я думаю, что иногда лучше что-то на небольшое время сохранить в сессии, чем отправлять туда-сюда (клиент-сервер). Ну а если объекты ОЧЕНЬ большого размера, то для этого - другая история (например, сохранять во временном файле, а путь к файлу держать в сессии). А вот данные о пользователе - мелочь памяти.